# Djnago how to split users and customres

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

In my project (small online shop) I need to split registration for users and customers.

So the information what I found when somebody registered in django then his account stored in one table, in this table I can see admin user and staff and another registered accounts, and I can sse them all in admin on Users page. But I do not want ot put all accounts in one "basket". I need split them fro different tables.

For example superuser can create in admin area a new user (content manager) and provide him access/permission to manage admin area (create product etc.) - this users and super user will be on default User page. On the page Customers will be displaying only users who registered for example via https://mysite/account/register page, after registration this customer account I can see in Customers page in the admin area but not in Users page. And this customer can login to his account for example via https://mysite/account/login

Is this possible?

Comment: The Users table is part of the authentication system, I wouldn't recommend separating people like that, all your registered customers are still Users. You could add a "customers" group and add people to it

Answer (score 3):

As Jay said, everyone registered in the database is still a User whatever their role may be (admin, superuser, customer). What you could do is create a `Profile` model where everyone will have their information such as telephone, location etc, and you will also add another field clarifying their `property`.

```
PACKAGES = [
    ('customer', 'Customer'),
    ('support', 'Support'),
    ('admin', 'Admin'),
]

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='user_avatar.png', upload_to='...')
    last_visit = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    user_role = models.CharField(default="customer", choices=PACKAGES, max_length=20)
```

Then all you need to do is edit your `admin.py` to implement a search parameter there:

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter=('user_role',)

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

Doing that will give you a `filter_list` in the right corner of your `admin` page but that is for admin page only.

If you want to access different `roles` in your views or your templates you will do so by getting the `user_role` you need:

```
customers = Profile.objects.filter(user_role='customer')
```

Comment: Why did you extend **OneToOnefield** on the Default User instead of a **Foreign Key**